# "name error: name 'admin' is not defined" error while trying to alter admin form for django

Tags: python, django

Guys I am following "https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/" tutorial and I successfully created models and displayed. But when I am trying to alter admin form its giving me error "name error: name 'admin' is not defined. I also need help from any of you guys to give me a simple but complete worked project as that will be easy for me to dig out problems. I am using Notepad ++, python 2.7 and Django 1.5. Using mysql workbench as db.

In models.py I have

```
class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
fields = ['pub_date', 'question']

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.admin
```

In admin.py I got

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Poll

admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

Thanking you in advance for your kind replies.

Answer (score 2):

You should define PollAdmin in admin.py, not in models.py.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from polls.models import Poll

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['pub_date', 'question']
admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

Comment: How exactly in admin py?

Comment: Exactly like you do in models.py

Comment: Or move `admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)` to `models.py`, though it is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in my to-string method, I used the field without using the self.
def **str**(self):
return f'{self.first_name}-score {score}'
This will give you the name error, while
def **str**(self):
return f'{self.first_name}-score {self.score}'
will correct it for you.
I hope it works for you!